# How to load some of many objects while browsing a page

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

In Facebook, as we scroll downwards it keeps loading posts one by one. How can I do this in Django? What else do I need to use?

Is it good practice to pass all the required objects from views to templates, so that it doesn't take so much time?

Comment: What you're looking for is called "infinite scroll," and requires javascript.  In Django, create two templates and associated controllers-- one generates the whole page, the other just generates "more" posts.  When the user scrolls toward the bottom, an ajax call can fetch those "more" posts (using the position of the last as a "where to start" index) and append them to the DIV that is your post container.

Answer (score 0):

A general overview of the how the process could work:

- The page loads with a subset of all images.
- Upon scrolling to a certain location the webpage issues an **AJAX** request to a 'load more' URL on the django server. Either as GET/POST parameters or as part of the url the AJAX request contains information to indicates the current position in the queryset (how many have been loaded so far). The webpage has a function, lets say `recievedMore`, this function is provided to the AJAX call as a callback.
- The 'load_more' URL is backed by a `load_more` django view. The `load_more` view uses the information in the AJAX request to filter a QuerySet down to the next set of images that will be shown. The view uses the filtered QuerSet to render a snipit of HTML and returns that as the response to the AJAX request.
- The webpage receives the response, calling the `recievedMore` function with the data from the server. The `recievedMore` function appends the response to an appropriate element on the page.

Using an [Infinite Scrolling](http://www.jquery4u.com/tutorials/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/) library and [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) on the client side makes implementation of this much easier.

[Django Pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/) is also relevant.

Answer (score -1):

you can use [infinite scroll](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/) 
its a jquery plugin that makes ajax requests - and put the response in its place in the markup

Django's generic ListView supports pagination out of the box

use it like this:

```
import models
from django.views.generic import ListView

class ObjectListView(ListView):
    model = SomeModel
    template_name = 'app/model_list.html'
    context_object_name = "objects"
    paginate_by = 10
```

now in your templates:
check if there is a next page of items using:
`page_obj.has_previous`
then feed that url to  infinite scroll:
`?page={{ objects.next_page_number }}`